# Triple Integral of $2y+x^2$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the volume of the solid region that is bounded above by the surface $f(x,y)=2y+x^2$, bounded below by the $xy$-plane and lies over the region in the $xy$-plane given by $[2,4]\times[-3,2]$
BE CAREFUL!!

This seems really basic, is it really as easy as:

$$\int_2^4\int_{-3}^2\int_0^{2y+x^2} 2y+x^2 dz dy dx$$

This seems to easy and i was told "Be careful!!!" so I think I may be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You only need to integrate in two dimensions.  The naive approach would be $$\int_2^4\int_{-3}^2 2y+x^2  dy dx$$  The "be careful" comes because some of the volume is below the $xy$ plane (for example,the point $(2,-3)$ and an area around it) so you need to work harder on the limits of integration.

Comment: So the y-bounds should be changed to [0,2]?
Thanks for the responses guys, I completely forgot volume was just the triple integral of 1.

Comment: @user73064:  no, the bounds are not a nice rectangle.  Note that $(2,-2)$ is in the area of integration.  If you are going to integrate in $y$ first (as this is written, and is a good idea) you consider $x$ fixed for that integral.  The limits in $y$ can depend on $x$.  So you should solve $2y+x^2\ge 0 \cap y \in [-3,2]$ for $y$ in terms of $x$ and use that for your limits.

Comment: @user73064:  you will have to split the range in $x$.  For some of it, the lower limit on $y$ needs to be modified.  For some of it, not, because $2y+x^2 \ge 0$ for all the $y \in [-3,2]$

Comment: Okay, so 2y+x^2 has to be greater than or equal to 0, so y has to be greater than or equal -x^2/2 so the y bounds should be changed to (-x^2/2,2), correct?

Comment: @user73064:  that is the right idea, but when $x \ge 2\sqrt 3$ you don't change the lower limit.  So you want $\left(\int_2^{2\sqrt 3}dx\int_{-x^2/2}^2dy + \int_{2\sqrt 3}^4 dx \int_{-3}^2 dy\right)2y+x^2$

Comment: Sorry for needing to have this spoon-fed, but where does the 2root3 come from? I know that's x^2=12 but when would x^2 ever have to equal 12?

Comment: @user73064:  the point is that for $x \gt 2 \sqrt 3, (2y+x^2)$ is always $\ge 0$ with $y \in [-3,2]$.  So you can do the integral over the whole range.  For $x \lt 2 \sqrt 3, (2y+x^2)$ can go negative, so you need to cut off the $y$ range appropriately.

Comment: But by that logic, x>√6 should make 2y+x^2>=0 because the minimum value of y is -3, and plugging that in gives -6+x^2>=0 which gives x>=√6

Comment: @user73064: you are correct.  I got the factor $2$ outside the square root, not inside.

Comment: No problem, that was throwing me off but I get it now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The volume of an element is given by $\iiint dxdydz$. On $z$-axis, it is bound below by $0$ and on top by $2y + x^2$ so your volume is given by
$$ \int_2^4 \int_{-3}^2\int_0^{2y + x^2}dzdydx$$